# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getTetherableIfaces on Lollipop

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

My application needs to check whether there is an available USB tetherable interface. For this it uses reflection to call getTetherableIfaces on the ConnectivityManager.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getTetherableIfaces");
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(cm, args);
```

I've tested this on a LG Leon running Android 5.0.1 and it fails with a java.lang.NoSuchMethodException.

Has this functionality been dropped or changed in Lollipop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.1_r1/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java#ConnectivityManager.getTetherableIfaces%28%29 the method still exists.

Maybe you should try `ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("getTetherableIfaces")` instead.

Have you tried to see the list of all metods for connectivity manager ? Can you show us the logs of the following code.

```
Method[] methodArray = ConnectivityManager.class.getMethods();
for (Method method : methodArray) {
   Log.v(TAG, method.getName());
}
```

Comment: ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod worked, thanks. After debugging the device I found out that  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) returns a subclass of ConnectivityManager, and calling getDeclaredMethod on this instance only returns the subclass' methods, NOT the methods in the ConnectivityManager. Calling getMethod is the right solution.